# Eigen Space of $A$ is the column space of which matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to find the projection matrix in the context of Principal Component Analysis (PCA). I know that projecting onto a column space of a matrix $A$ effectively turns to multiplying by the projection matrix $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$. But in PCA, we are projecting onto the eigenvectors of $A$ so in order to apply my knowledge of projections, I need to know what is the matrix $B$ whose column space is the same as the eigenspace of $A$. My intuition is that $B$ is the matrix formed by the eigenvectors of $A$ stacked along columns. Am I right?